# Find outliers of data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, statistics

I am attempting to find the outliers of seconds with standard deviations. I have two dataframes as below. The outliers I am trying to find are 1.5 standard deviations away from the mean by day of week?  Current code is below the dataframes.

df1:

```
name    dateTime              Seconds
joe     2015-02-04 12:12:12   54321.0202
john    2015-01-02 13:13:13   12345.0101
joe     2015-02-04 12:12:12   54321.0202
john    2015-01-02 13:13:13   12345.0101
joe     2015-02-04 12:12:12   54321.0202
john    2015-01-02 13:13:13   12345.0101
joe     2015-02-04 12:12:12   54321.0202
john    2015-01-02 13:13:13   12345.0101
joe     2015-02-04 12:12:12   54321.0202
john    2015-01-02 13:13:13   12345.0101
joe     2015-02-04 12:12:12   54321.0202
joe     2015-01-02 13:13:13   12345.0101
```

current output: df2

```
name   day   standardDev        mean           count
Joe    mon   22326.502700       40900.730647   1886
       tue   9687.486726        51166.213836   159
john   mon   10072.707891       41380.035108   883
       tue   5499.475345        26985.938776   196
```

Expected output:

df2

```
name   day   standardDev        mean           count     events
Joe    mon   22326.502700       40900.730647   1886      [2015-02-04 12:12:12, 2015-02-04 12:12:13]
       tue   9687.486726        51166.213836   159       [2015-02-04 12:12:12, 2015-02-04 12:12:14]
john   mon   10072.707891       41380.035108   883       [2015-01-02 13:13:13, 2015-01-02 13:13:15]
       tue   5499.475345        26985.938776   196       [2015-01-02 13:13:13, 2015-01-02 13:13:18]
```

CODE:

```
allFiles = glob.glob(folderPath + "/*.csv")
list_ = []
for file_ in allFiles:
    df = pd.read_csv(file_, index_col=None, names=['EventTime', "IpAddress", "Hostname", "TargetUserName", "AuthenticationPackageName", "TargetDomainName", "EventReceivedTime"])
    df = df.ix[1:]
    list_.append(df)
df = pd.concat(list_)
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EventTime'])
df['day_of_week'] = df.DateTime.dt.strftime('%a')
df['seconds'] = pd.to_timedelta(df.DateTime.dt.time.astype(str)).dt.seconds
print(df.groupby((['TargetUserName', 'day_of_week'])).agg({'seconds': {'mean': lambda x: (x.mean()), 'std': lambda x: (np.std(x)), 'count': 'count'}}))
```

Comment: Maybe `df1[df1.groupby(pd.DatetimeIndex(df.dateTime).dayofweek)['Seconds'].apply(lambda x: x > (1.5*x.std() + x.mean()))]`?

Comment: what do you exactly mean by "I am unsure how to get to the expected output. "?

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to add the events column and track all events that are 1.5 standard deviations away from the mean both up and down? Ideally, I would like to add any row with full data,  that is outside of the time period to the events column as a list of events.

Comment: @johnnyb, what I provided earlier is not complete because it only found values above `1.5*std + mean`. But try `df1[df1.groupby(pd.DatetimeIndex(df.dateTime).dayofweek)['Seconds'].\
apply(lambda x: (x > (1.5*x.std() + x.mean())) | (x < (-1.5*x.std() + x.mean())))]`.

Comment: The way I am reading your suggestion, I think its only going to put the event time in seconds in the event column List. Would there be an easy way to put the entire log row that matches that event time by day of week and by person into the list? I also get a "AssertionError: Grouper and axis must be same length" error when attempting this line of code. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I would pretty much do it like @Abdou although I'd make the groupby:  `groupby(['name',df.dateTime.dt.day])`.  Also take a look at the docs, there's  a standard zscore example there:  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation

Comment: @johnnyb  generally speaking you don't want to put multiple entries in once cell (pandas is just not set up to work like that for one thing).  You're likely better off just selecting all rows that fit the criterion.  You can format however you like later on, but you don't want to store in a dataframe like that.

Comment: @JohnE I am geting a KeyError: 'TargetUserName' when running the code below:

Comment: df1[df1.groupby(['TargetUserName', df['DateTime'].dt.day])'Events'].apply(lambda x: (x > (1.5*x.std() + x.mean())) | (x < (-1.5*x.std() + x.mean())))]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a slight adaptation from the [pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation).  I didn't create columns for mean & std, but you could add that pretty easily if you want to see it.

```
np.random.seed(1111)
df=pd.DataFrame({ 'name':     ['joe','john']*30, 
                  'dateTime': pd.date_range('1-1-2015',periods=60),
                  'Seconds':  np.random.randn(60)+5000. })

grp = df.groupby(['name',df.dateTime.dt.dayofweek])['Seconds']
df['zscore'] = grp.transform( lambda x: (x-x.mean())/x.std())

df[ df['zscore'].abs() > 1.5 ]
Out[79]: 
        Seconds   dateTime  name    zscore
1   4998.927011 2015-01-02  john -1.522488
42  5001.275866 2015-02-12   joe  1.636829
58  4999.124550 2015-02-28   joe -1.624945

df.head(10)
Out[80]:
       Seconds   dateTime  name    zscore
0  4998.699990 2015-01-01   joe -0.959960
1  4998.927011 2015-01-02  john -1.522488
2  5000.790199 2015-01-03   joe  0.263690
3  4999.121735 2015-01-04  john -1.005137
4  5001.501822 2015-01-05   joe  1.132407
5  4999.976071 2015-01-06  john  0.678951
6  5000.275949 2015-01-07   joe  0.650297
7  4999.033607 2015-01-08  john -0.964222
8  4998.419685 2015-01-09   joe -1.328744
9  4999.796325 2015-01-10  john  1.224198
```

Comment: Is it calculating a zscore for every user for every day of the week for that user? I am trying to find people that fall out of the 1.5 for the specific day of the week based on their patterns of time

Comment: Yep.  You could check a particular person/day of week like this:  `df[ (df.dateTime.dt.dayofweek == 1) & (df.name == 'joe') ]`  and also make mean & std columns if that makes it more clear.